# Why is Vert.x executing code synchronously?

Tags: javascript, java, asynchronous, future, vert.x

Need help with understanding the code execution flow.
On calling the `sayHi()` method below, the `onSuccess` handler is executed first and then the `return` statement gets executed.
I had the understanding that the function will return immediately and the `onSuccess` handler will get executed after that.

```
public String sayHi() {
    sayHello().onSuccess(s  -> {
      System.out.println(s);
    });
    return "hi";
  }

  public Future<String> sayHello() {
    String s1 = "hello";
    return Future.succeededFuture(s1);
  }
```

EDIT: I'm trying to draw a comparison it with JavaScript Promises, where the function passed to the `then` method always gets executed after the rest of the statements are executed. Like calling the `test` method below will print 'hi','bye' and **then** 'Success'

```
    var promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve("Success!")
    });
      
   function test() {
      console.log("hi");
      promise2.then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      });
      console.log("bye");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Future.succeededFuture(s1)` returns an already completed `Future` that is not associated with an ExecutionContext.

Since it is already completed and not associated with an ExecutionContext it executes the `onSuccess()` handler synchronously.

You need to tell vert.x to create the `Future<String>` for you on a separate thread. You can try

```
import io.vertx.core.Future;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;

public class Async {
    private static Vertx vertx;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        System.out.println(sayHi());
        vertx.close();
    }
    public static String sayHi() {
        sayHello().onSuccess(s  -> {
            System.out.println(s);
        });
        return "hi";
    }

    public static Future<String> sayHello() {
        return vertx.executeBlocking(p -> {
            String s1 = "hello";
            p.complete(s1);
        });
    }
}
```

Note: I don't have much experience with vert.x, so there could be better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_future_results):

> You cannot interact directly with the result of a future, instead you
> need to set a handler **that will be called when the future completes
> and the result is available**, like any other kind of event.

So the `Future` result is available immediately and there is no I/O task to wait for: like an HTTP response, or reading from file system...etc.

All your code is running in a single thread you can verify it yourself:

```
public String sayHi() {
    sayHello().onSuccess(s  -> {
      System.out.println("Thread name ==> " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); // e.g: Thread name ==> main
      System.out.println(s);
    });
    return "hi";
  }

  public Future<String> sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Thread name ==> " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); // e.g: Thread name ==> main
    String s1 = "hello";
    return Future.succeededFuture(s1);
  }
```

But the code below may run in different order (we are doing I/O task here):

```
  public String sayHi() {
    sayHello().onSuccess(s  -> {
      System.out.println(s);
    });
    return "hi";
  }

  public Future<String> sayHello() {
    var vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    var fs = vertx.fileSystem();
    return fs.props( ".").map(fileProps -> "In getHelloFuture() method");  // I/O task
  }
```